# WithOptional with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate my old app to the new EF Core but I cannot find some relationships like:

```
  HasRequired(o => o.Document).WithOptional(o => o.CancelNote);
```

Is there some extension methods? I cannot find on the docs.

The `HasRequired` I think that is possible to substitute with `HasOne()` method, but how about the `WithOptional()`?

Other thing, according to the [docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html) the entity not uses the `virtual` keyword to create the navigation properties, how lazy load will work?

Comment: Can you please provide class declaration for Document and CancelNote

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will not find an `HasOptional` equivalent method in EF7. By convention if your FK property is [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you navigation property will be treated as optional

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Document)
                .WithOne(i => i.CancelNote)
                .HasForeignKey<Document>(b => b.CancelNoteForeignKey);
```

About your second question,EF Core (EF7) doesn't support Lazy Loading. In this [link](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/related-data.html) you will find the options you have now to load related entities

Comment: But my FK property is the Document entity:  *public virtual Document Document {get;set;}*  This property should be nullable?

Comment: No, what you are pointing out is a navigation property, your FK property should be: `public int? CancelNoteForeignKey{get;set;}`

Comment: Does the HasOne() is replacement for HasOptional()?

Comment: How to specify HasForeignKey without knowing class models and Foreign property

Comment: Can you please provide the Class model for regarding this relationship, so easy to understand the concept