# One-to-Zero relationship with Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating a Entity Framework 6.1.3 Code First library to Entity Framework Core with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I've been searching about Entity Framework Core with Google but I haven't found many information about it so I have try to do it by myself.

On Entity Framework 6.1.3 I have this configuration class:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Configurations
{
    class AggregationChildrenConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AggregationChildren>
    {
        public AggregationChildrenConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationChildrenId);

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
                .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationId);

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
                .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I have migrated to this one:

```
using DataLibrary;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace BusinessLibrary.Configurations
{
    class AggregationChildrenConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AggregationChildren>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AggregationChildren> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationChildrenId);

            builder.HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
                .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationId);

            builder.HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
                .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But builder hasn't got `HasRequired` method, and I think the others methods `WithOptional`, `WithMany` and `WillCascadeOnDelete` either.

I have migrated to this, but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
using DataLibrary;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using System;

namespace BusinessLibrary.Configurations
{
    class AggregationChildrenConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AggregationChildren>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AggregationChildren> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationChildrenId);

            builder.HasOne(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
                .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChildren)
                .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
                .WithOne(c => c.AggregationChild)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
```

I've been checking [EntityTypeBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder) documentation but I don't know which methods do I have to use instead or if this is the right way to migrate to Entity Framework Core.

This relationship is not one-to-zero:

```
builder.HasOne(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
    .WithOne(c => c.AggregationChild)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

In this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38513960/68571) said that I have to put ForeignKey to null it will set it as optional, but I can't set `Code.CodeId` as nullable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The EF6 setup is creating a so called [One-To-One Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) where the PK of the dependent entity is also a FK to principal entity.

The things have changed in EF Core. It supports naturally both shared PK and FK one-to-one associations. Also optional/required are not used to determine the  principal and dependent ends of the association. `IsRequired` is used to control if the dependent entity can exists w/o principal and applies only whith separate FK. While `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrincipalKey` are used to determine the principal and dependent ends of the association and also map the dependent FK and principal PK / Alternate Key.

With that being said, the equivalent EFC configuration is as follows:

```
builder.HasOne(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
    .WithOne(c => c.AggregationChild)
    .HasForeignKey<AggregationChildren>(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationChildrenId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

So we start with defining the relationship using `HasOne` + `WithOne`.

Then `HasForeignKey<AggregationChildren>(ag_ch => ag_ch.AggregationChildrenId)` to tell EF that (1) `AggregationChildren` is the dependent end of the relationship, and (2) that the PK `AggregationChildrenId` should also be used as FK.

Finally, `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` is the EFC equivalent of the EF6 `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`. The other options like `ClientSetNull` and `SetNull` apply only when the dependent has a separate optional FK, which is not the case with shared PK association.

Reference: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is something that I haven't understood: where is you telling that the relationship from Code to AggregationChildren is optional?

Comment: There is no need in this case. Only dependent entity with separate FK may have optional or required. See the description on `IsRequired` method - *"Configures whether this is a required relationship (i.e. whether the foreign key property(s) can be assigned null)."*. EF6 use optional/required terms for different purpose. In EFC by default relationships are optional except you have explicit separate non nullable FK property.

Comment: In my case, this simply doesn't work. I have tried to define `HasForeignKey` on both the parent and the child, and it always ends up on the parent. I have tried specifying the child as the generic type, and the parent as the generic type, and it _still_ always ends up on the parent.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah No way. Apparently you are doing something wrong. First, there must be only 1 definition of the relationship (in order to be sure you are not creating conflicting relationship configuration). Second, the FK must be defined for child(dependent) entity. That's it. Parent(principal) never has as FK.