# Convert WithOptional to Entity Framework Core(7) equivalent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Im migrating a project from .Net 4.X to .Net 6 and EF 6 to the latest version (version 7 i believe) using Visual Studio 2022.

I've migrated a bunch of configurations but the below im not sure the best way to proceed (the database already exists)

Here is EF6 code

```
internal class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.CustomerDocuments)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustomerID);
    }
}
```

In EF 7 i have the code as

```
internal class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(e => e.CustomerDocuments)
    }
}
```

But i cant find the equivalent for `.WithOptional` and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key doesnt really show me any example of how i can configure it although `.HasForeignKey` seems to exist but i think once `WithOptional` is resolved it may give some way to convert/use `HasForeignKey`.

I read [WithOptional with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513232/withoptional-with-entity-framework-core) but then i get confused with if its replacement is `HasOne` as im already using `WithOne` (in another Entity configuration) to convert `WithRequired` (from EF 6)

Anyone know what im missing here or how to convert to the equivalent in EF 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core these are simply separated to `WithOne` (for relationship cardinality and associated reference navigation property mapping) and `IsRequired` (whether it required/optional).

So the general conversion of EF6 `WithOptional` / `WithRequired` after `HasMany` / `HasOne` to EF Core is like

```cs
.WithOptional(e => e.Customer)
```

maps to

```cs
.WithOne(e => e.Customer)
.IsRequired(false)
```

and

```cs
.WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
```

maps to

```cs
.WithOne(e => e.Customer)
.IsRequired(true) // or just .IsRequired()
```

The same applies if you start configuration from the "one" side, i.e. `HasOptional` / `HasRequired` become `HasOne().With{One|Many}).IsRequired(false|true)`

Comment: Thanks, so if i've understood you the end code should be             
                'builder.HasMany(e => e.CustomerDocuments)'
                '.WithOne(e => e.Customer)'
                '.IsRequired(false)'
                '.HasForeignKey(e => e.CustomerID);'

Comment: Exactly. I was assuming (could be wrong of course) that it is obvious that the code snippets replace just the mentioned line (fluent API call) and the rest remains the same as in EF6.

Comment: Reason why i double checked was i found it strange where one line of code in EF6 now becomes two for WithOptional in EF7

Comment: @Computer Not a problem at all. Even though the answer starts with a sentence that the method in question is now separated to two :) Anyway, glad it helped.